Issues with "Remember Me" Functionality and Redirect After Login Using Jetstream and Livewire in Laravel 11
I'm experiencing an issue with the "Remember Me" functionality in a Laravel 11 application using Jetstream with Livewire. Although the session lifetime is set to expire after 2 hours, and both the remember me cookie is correctly set in the browser, and the database column for the remember me token is populated, I still have to log in again after the session expires. This occurs despite having checked the "Remember Me" option during login. How can I ensure that the "Remember Me" feature works correctly, keeping users logged in beyond the session expiry?
Also after logging in, I am redirected to the / route instead of the custom route specified in the Fortify 'home' configuration. How can ensure that the post-login redirection respects my custom configuration?
